# How to retrive exact number from string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

As i am new to regular expression i want to fetch exact number from string.I here paste code that i tried please tell me solution.In below code i can fetched number 4000 and 1 but i want only 4000 not 1 which is with 'a'

```
 $str = "4000+a1";
 preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $str, $matches);
 return $matches;
```

Comment: Use `preg_match` and then use `$matches[0]`. Why `preg_match_all`???  It is matching all digits and returning an array of them.  What do you need?

Comment: then you can try `preg_match_all('/[0-9]{4}/', $str, $matches);`

Comment: my string can be "4000+a1+1000" in this case i want 4000 and 1000

Comment: That's good info to have in the question, don't you think?

Comment: What's the pattern?  They are 4 digits or what?

Comment: that can be any number

Comment: @AbraCadaver, no need to be furious. In the question, he stated **not 1 which is with 'a'**. You can guess/imply that he doesn't want the number together with a letter

Comment: @Erwin: Really? so `4000+a1+1000b` or `4000+a1+x1000` shouldn't capture the `1000`? That's your guess?  Then please answer and edit your question until you are ready to hang yourself. :-) Especially given the comment _my string can be "4000+a1+1000" in this case i want 4000 and 1000_ it is very UNCLEAR what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this pattern

```
$str = "4000+a1";
preg_match_all('/\b\d+\b/', $str, $matches);
return $matches;
```

`\b` - asserts position at a boundary
`\d+` - matches a digit, one to unlimited times

Comment: Well done why?  Most don't even know what you want to capture.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The question's actually easy to understand. Maybe you just refuse to do so. ;)

Comment: @Emerald: That wasn't directed at you, but capture me these numbers but not these.  Wait there's more, I want these other numbers.  Congrats.

Answer (score -1):

You could start at the beginning of the string by using the ^ symbol.

```
$str = "4000+a1";
preg_match_all('/^[0-9]+/', $str, $matches);
return $matches;
```